# Неправильное выполнение заданий cron

Tags: cron

Как запустить одновременно 4 задачи?

```
/usr/bin/php /home/user1781/public_html/monster/test.php ?query=1
*/1 *   *   *   *
/usr/bin/php /home/user1781/public_html/monster/test.php ?query=2
*/1 *   *   *   *
/usr/bin/php /home/user1781/public_html/monster/test.php ?query=3
*/1 *   *   *   *
/usr/bin/php /home/user1781/public_html/monster/test.php ?query=4
*/1 *   *   *   *
```

Answer (score 3):

Прописать все четыре в один shell скрипт, который и вызывать из крона:

```
### zada4a.sh
/usr/bin/php /home/user1781/public_html/monster/test.php query=1
/usr/bin/php /home/user1781/public_html/monster/test.php query=2
/usr/bin/php /home/user1781/public_html/monster/test.php query=3
/usr/bin/php /home/user1781/public_html/monster/test.php query=4
```

В кроне:

```
/home/user1781/zada4a.sh
```

И да, это вопрос больше не по программированию, а по серверным делам — на [РутКод](http://admin.hashcode.ru/).